# SelectModelImpl Non-Serializable Prevents Session Replication in Cluster

Tags: tapestry

I'm working on clustering an application using Tapestry 5.3.3. Clustering is accomplished by replicating the HttpSession to all nodes in the cluster. The replication occurs by serializing the HttpSession. When the container attempts to serialize the session a NotSerializableException is thrown because org.apache.tapestry5.internal.SelectModelImpl is not serializable. Tapestry adds this class to the session through the ClusteredSessionImpl class. So it does appear Tapestry wants to be cluster friendly by saving relevant information to the session. Any thoughts on how to get around this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tapestry user mailing list provided some good suggestions. Evidently, persisting a SelectModel to the session should be avoided. Here's a couple of responses -

---

Is it your custom code that is @Persist ing the SelectModel? If so, you could @Persist the underlying Collection instead and build the SelectModel in the UI each time. You should remember that HTTPSession usage should be kept to a minimum, especially in a clustered environment. HTTPSession usage doesn't scale well.
Do you really need to persist a list in the session? Could you instead just store a user id (or other filter parameter) in the session and look up the list each time it is needed from a service? If you find later that the lookup is expensive, you could look at caching at the service level.

You should read this:
http://tapestry.apache.org/performance-and-clustering.html

---

Don't @Persist or @SessionState SelectModel. That's a bad idea. As Lance said, if you really need to persist it somehow, persist a List that is used to create the SelectModel, not the SelectModel itself.

---